# What mammal or creature dropped this? (Warning: Gross Pictures)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, ornithology, excreta

I'm at a loss to explain what creature dropped or created this. This giant pile showed up virtually overnight.  If someone could point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

The geographical area is Sparks, Nevada.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably a bird, or more likely a group of birds.

Comment: I know piles of poop like the one sown in your picture from swallows... Barn swallows for example. Is there a nest somewhere above?

Comment: Yep, looks like it was 2 birds hiding in the roof soffit.  Didn't think there was an opening in the soffit directly above the pile, but I guess there is.  Couldn't get a good look at what kind of bird they were.  They shan't be returning, however.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can see a similar pile of bird poop seen below a [barn swallow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barn_swallow) nest:

[image]

<sup>Source: [deepmuckbigrake](http://deepmuckbigrake.com/2011/07/12/barn-swallows/)</sup>

Alternatively, if it really did appear overnight, perhaps a pile pf pigeon poop was pushed out of a nesting area in the soffit?

[image]

<sup>Source: [Scranton Times Tribune](https://www.thetimes-tribune.com/news/pigeon-poop-plagues-pair-of-scranton-parking-garages-1.1531180)</sup>

If it's pigeon poop, [you might want to be careful](http://www.progressivepestmanagement.com/pigeons-renosparks-nv/).